# How can I open my compiled OpenGL application with a double click?

Tags: unity, launcher, opengl

I have written a custom OpenGL application.

I can launch it from terminal with `./basic_cube` but when I double click on it from within a file browser, I get the following error:

[image]

How can I launch this executable program with a double click?

Comment: What does `file basic_cube` say? And what's your linking command?

Comment: The output of `file` is `basic_cube: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=51c34614372f93a88b8f72bb88d59c6b83a9428d, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped` What do you mean "linking command"?

Comment: I meant the command you use to produce the executable, in your Makefile or somesuch, or the last one that is executed... Anyway from your reply it seems this is not relevant and the error will be probably somewhere else.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1237154/66509 . I have self-written solution.