# Can only start arduino-ide from terminal

Tags: nautilus

I have downloaded the new Arduino IDE 2.0 Beta and extracted the zip into a suitable directory.

If I open the directory in Nautilus and double-click on arduino-ide I get a warning that the "arduino-ide" cannot be opened and that there is no software installed that for the datatype "common library". (Sorry, but I translated that warning from the German, on an English language machine it might be phrased differently.")

However if I open a terminal and cd to the directory containing arduino-ide and then type ./arduino-ide the IDE launches and everything works as expected..

The file arduino-idea is executable, otherwise it wouldn't run in the terminal. I am using Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Use umake instead - https://askubuntu.com/a/1025755/66509 .

Comment: The Aduino IDE 2.0 is a Beta software, I do not want to replace my existing Aduino IDE 1.8.13 with it, I just want to test it. I guess my question is why does arduino-ide work from the command line but not from Nautilus because that is not norman behaviour for an executable.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/1237154/66509 for another way of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom desktop launcher for Arduino IDE beta version and then use it.

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/

cat <<EOF > ~/.local/share/applications/arduino-beta.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Arduino IDE beta
Icon=/home/$USER/path-to/arduino-beta/lib/arduino_icon.ico
Exec=/home/$USER/path-to/arduino-beta/arduino-executable
Comment=The Arduino Software IDE
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
EOF
```

Note: adjust `Exec` and `Icon` paths before copying and pasting above code to terminal.

Comment: Thanks. But I would still like to know why the arduino-ide works in the terminal but not in Nautilus.

Comment: It is a bug in some library which is used by Nautilus (and really other file-managers like Caja). See https://pad.lv/1877591 for details and links.